# Charge of $W$-bosons in Feynman diagrams

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, charge, feynman-diagrams

When looking at Feynman diagrams of particle decays, how would I be able to find out the charges of the $W$-bosons involved in the decay?

Comment: Conservation of charge!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439896/

Answer (score 0):

At a vertex of the diagram the usual conservation rules apply. Lepton number, charge and so on...

Comment: This answer could be better if you included an example of a Feynman diagram that involved the W-boson.

Comment: This would be more complete if you noted that this rules work reliably for time-like $W$'s but is ambiguous for space-like $W$ exchanges.